# Abnormal 'buffer:' string in Windows awk result

Tags: windows, awk

Can you help me out?
When I use a regular expression in awk script, strangely I got 'buffer:' messages as well like below.
This issue doesn't happen in my Windows 10(English language pack) but I always see the issue in Windows 10(Korean language pack).
I am not sure the issue is related to windows language pack but the same issue happens in 2 machines(Korean language pack).

## Data

```
Find 234
No
Find 111
no
test
```

## AWK script

```
/Find[[:space:]]+[0-9]/ {   
print $0;   
}
```

## Output

```
buffer: 2
buffer: 2
Find 234
buffer: 1
buffer: 1
Find 111
```

Comment: Whatever this issue is it has nothing to do with awk. You should remove the awk tag and re-tag it with Windows or something else related to the environment you run awk from.

Comment: How can you say this issue is not related to awk? Can you please let me know why is?

Comment: Because awk does not issue random messages like "buffer: 2" and there is nothing in your awk script that could produce that output. You need to look into whatever OS/environment you are running awk from.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will try to make a workaround on this issue. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Please add details of your environment; how are you running awk? From cygwin, a native windows version...?

Comment: It looks like you're getting some debug output interwoven with the output you expected.  You haven't provided enough clues for us to figure out where that came from.  I suppose you could ignore it with `awk '/Find[[:space:]]+[0-9]/' Data.txt |grep -v ^buffer:` (assuming the buffer lines are on standard output) or `awk '/Find[[:space:]]+[0-9]/' Data.txt 2>/dev/null` (assuming the buffer lines are on standard error).